# Batch file, xcopy from subfolders

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory, xcopy

Hi I found this batch file script in a previous thread which kinda works but does anyone know how to make this search sub folders? if I use the absolute destination it works perfectly however I need it to search various folders.

```
set src_folder=Z:\Digital Packages\
set dst_folder=Z:\Build\2013\September2013\test\test
set file_list=Z:\List\files.txt

if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"

for /r "delims=" %%r in (%file_list%) do (
    xcopy "%src_folder%\%%r" "%dst_folder%\"
```

Comment: could you please provide some example of the contents of the file list and the structure of the src and dest folder

Comment: `for /r` doesn't read a file and `"delims="` isn't used by `/r` either.  Your code above won't work.  IIRC `XXcopy` from http://www.xxcopy.com can take an include list and is free for personal use.

Comment: The files.txt contained file names such as;
barcode_00_00.ext

Comment: The files.txt contained file names such as;
barcode_03_02.ext
barcode_01_04.ext 
barcode_02_01.ext 

The Src structure isnt standard in "most" places its;
Z:\Digital Packages\year\Month\Barcode\

The Dest folder will be fairly standard with additional months/year folders.

f the source folder path is absolute it works, it copies all the files listed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the /s option.  See XCOPY /?

Comment: I need it to search through sub folders of Z:\Digital Packages\ and copyy the files listed in the text file. Apologies if that was not clear.